# Check if record exist and return a boolean and compare it with inputs from a form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi i am having troubles sorting this out as the title says i am trying to check if a record exist and return a boolean instead of the record value from the database so i can compare it with a filter form, i know this can be solved using nested if's but i'm trying to find a better way, this is my code so far

```
public function getSend(){
            if($this->request->role==1){
                $id= Cv::select('cv.user_id','cv.pub')
                    ->where('cv.pub','==',$this->request->pub)
                    ->get();
                dd($id);


                return view('gestione.'.$this->view_namespace.'.send.pagina');
            }
```

my idea is something like this

```
->where('cv.pub','==',$this->request->pub)
```

this one works because "pub" stores a boolean record in my database alot of other records store strings for example

```
->where('cv.something','==',$this->request->something)
```

wouldnt work because "something" is a string and not a boolean so how do i turn "something" into a boolean based on if wheter exist or not

thanks in advance by the way i am using laravel 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
->where('cv.something','==',!empty($this->request->something))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$id = Cv::select('cv.user_id','cv.pub') // select is not required here
                ->where('cv.pub','==',$this->request->pub)
                ->exists();
```

Also, you may use it like:

```
if (Cv::where('cv.pub', $this->request->pub)->exists()) {
    // The record exists, so do something...
}
```

This query will return a boolean true if exists, otherwise false. You may also make the query conditionally depending on the `$this->request->pub` in one go, for example:

```
$exists = Cv::when($this->request->pub, function($query) {
    $query->where('cv.pub', $this->request->pub);
})->exists();

if ($exists) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this would work but the "exist" method doesnt exist in laravel 5.1

Comment: @Ivor92, it does, [check here](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_exists). Why don't just try it, anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$something = !empty($this->request->something);

if($something) {
    $exits = Cv::where('cv.'+$something, $something)->get();
    if($exits) {
        // Cv exits
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = Cv::select('cv.user_id','cv.pub')
                    ->where('cv.pub','==',$this->request->pub);
if($request->something){
$result = $result->whereNotNull('cv.something'); // or != '', depending how you store it
}
```

This is mostly how filters works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a boolean you can use `count()` :

```
$id= Cv::select('cv.user_id','cv.pub')
    ->where('cv.pub','==',$this->request->pub)
    ->count();
```

This will return the number of records, 0 if none, 1 if one is found. Obviously this will only work if 1 record is found, if 3 are found this solution wont work however I from what you have said it seems like that is all you will return.

Anything more than 0 means that a value exists.